# I want to set viewport in a page that os opened for page that opens as target blank

Tags: viewport

I am opening a PDF file to view in a new browser tab by setting `target="blank"` in the `anchor tag` and i want to set `viewport` in new tab that to make it mobile friendly.
how can I do this?